# Complex Table formatting in restructeredtext

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to generate a complex table with rows and columns spanning multiple cells. Below is a snapshot of my reST code.

[image: reST snapshot]

However, the Latex generated PDF output from Sphinx is not representing the format correctly.

[image: output PDF via Latex snapshot]

Please let me know what might be wrong in my reST format to correct this issue?

The HTML snapshot, as per comment, is attached below and it is correct.

[image: HTML Snapshot]

Thank you!

Comment: Some extra information that is useful: is the HTML output correct? If so, there might be a bug in the latex renderer. If not, there is a typo somewhere in your table.

Comment: Thanks, the HTML output is correct. Attached the snapshot in the original question.

Comment: Your reST code is correct because the HTML is correct. So that probably means an error in the convertion from reST to LaTeX. You've got two options: you can look at the `.tex` code yourself, if you know LaTeX, and try to spot the error (and perhaps you can find a workaround). Second option: report a bug (http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=38414&atid=422030) in the docutils project (point at this question here and give them the .rst and .tex code so they can check what's wrong).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug: the Docutils LaTeX writer fails with (some)
komplrc tables.
http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/latex.html#tables

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried it because I don't want to type that whole table, but rst2pdf should not have a problem processing that.

Comment: Hi, Yes rst2pdf processed it correctly. I needed the tex output and could not find a way to customize the rst2pdf file generation.

Comment: rst2pdf is fairly customizable, but it depends on what you want :-)

Of course if what you need is the TeX output it won't help.